# How to use livereload from multiple servers in a single page? (in particular with Grunt.js connect and watch)

Tags: gruntjs, livereload, grunt-contrib-watch

I am trying to get livereload working in one website, triggered by different servers, from different projects. I am using Grunt.js with grunt-contrib-connect and grunt-contrib-watch.

Here is an example:

- ProjectA is currently running a livereload server on localhost:33333
- ProjectB is currently running a livereload server on localhost:44444
- ProjectC is currently running a livereload server on localhost:55555

Now let's say, I run a webpage on localhost:9800 that should benefit from livereloading
So, in most cases where only one livereload process is present, one would have something like this in localhost:9800/index.html :

```
 
<body>
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//localhost:35729/livereload.js"></script>
</body>
```

so, with multiple livereload servers, I thought I'd have to include all livereload scripts:

```
 
<body>
...
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//localhost:33333/livereload.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//localhost:44444/livereload.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" src="//localhost:55555/livereload.js"></script>
</body>
```

which is not working. Only the first script will trigger livereload in the browser. In the docs of grunt-contrib-watch, they have an example about running different servers in different targets of the *watch* task. How do you actually make this work?

Thank you for any help

Here is my watch task for testing:

```
 
  watch: {

    css: {
      files: ['www/**/*.css'],
      options: {
        livereload: 33333
      }
    },

    html: {
      files: ['www/**/*.html'],
      options: {
        livereload: 44444
      }
    },

    js: {
      files: ['www/**/*.js'],
      options: {
        livereload: 55555
      }
    },
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This configuration could not work.

livereload.js instantiates a global object LiveReload see ( [livereload-js/src/startup.coffee](https://github.com/livereload/livereload-js/blob/master/src/startup.coffee) ).
And there is only one web-socket available per LiveReload object, so you could not have on 3 sockets.

I would like to have the same configuration as you, but today I do not find a work around for it